# How to check if current time falls between two time stamps in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to check if my current time stamp is between a time range.

for ex: I want to check my current time(let's say 03:00 PM) falls between 06:00 PM and 07:00 PM.

How do I check this in Oracle?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to see if the time-of-day component is between 6 pm and 7 pm, regardless of date?  How are you inputting (or storing) the start and end timestamps? In particular, in what data type?

Comment: Agreed. If you are checking to see if you are currently in a defined window of time, that is a completely different solution from checking to see if you are between a set of recurring business hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN SYSDATE - TRUNC( SYSDATE ) BETWEEN 17.5/24 AND 18.5/24
         THEN 'Is between 17:30 and 18:30'
         ELSE 'Not between 17:30 and 18:30'
       END
FROM   DUAL;
```

or

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN SYSDATE BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '17:30' HOUR TO MINUTE
                          AND TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '18:30' HOUR TO MINUTE
         THEN 'Is between 17:30 and 18:30'
         ELSE 'Not between 17:30 and 18:30'
       END
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: How do I write if I want to check in between 05:30 PM to 06:30 PM.Where do  I add minutes?

Comment: @Santosh Updated

Comment: @Santosh - in many cases, in business terms, "between 17:30 and 18:30" means >= 17:30 but < 18:30. (Especially if you look at several consecutive intervals.) If so, then you can use most of MT0's solution, but with inequalities as demonstrated by Torsten in his answer; BETWEEN has non-strict inequalities at both ends.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use strings for the comparision:

```
select
  case when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') >= '18:00' 
        and to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') <  '19:00' then 'YES' else 'NO'
  end as in_time_range
from dual;
```