# How to query between hours and minute in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
...
CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24')) BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 0 else count(*) end....
```

But I'd like to change until 4:30AM only (04:31 not apply anymore). How can I do it? I now I can get with `to_char(...,'hh24:mi')` but it will be a char value.

Also, I have tried:

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'hh24:mi'),'HH24:MI') from dual;
```

but the date goes wrong.

I want something like it:

```
CASE WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'hh24:mi') BETWEEN TO_DATE('02:00','HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('04:30','HH24:MI')
```

Comment: please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554304/how-to-check-if-current-time-falls-between-two-time-stamps-in-oracle

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can still do a range comparison using text hh:mm strings:

```sql
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'hh24') >= '02:00' AND
          TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'hh24') <= '04:30'
     THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) END
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data types:

```sql
CASE
WHEN (SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE)) DAY TO SECOND
     BETWEEN INTERVAL '02:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
         AND INTERVAL '04:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND
THEN 0
ELSE count(*)
END
```

Or, you can do the same with arithmetic:

```sql
CASE
WHEN (SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE)) BETWEEN 2/24 AND 4.5/24
THEN 0
ELSE count(*)
END
```